# Matrix inverses in function spaces

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Consider the following two matrices, $D$ and $S$, defined in a function space:

$$D=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$S=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & \frac12 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & \frac13 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I noticed that

$$DS=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}\right)=I$$

However

$$SD=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}\right)\neq I$$

Yet I was told that $AB=I\iff BA=I$. What is causing the discrepancy? Maybe I am wrong to say that $DS=I$, or maybe the proof that $AB=I\iff BA=I$ does not apply for infinitely sized matrices?

(Note: The proof I was told was that $AB=I\Rightarrow B=BI=B(AB)=(BA)B=IB\Rightarrow BA=I$.)

**Context:**

Some time ago, I learnt that the derivative and integral functions are both linear functions. More recently, I learnt that functions can be thought of as vectors and are in a function space. For the subset of continuous functions, we can use $x^0, x^1, x^2,\cdots$ as all continuous functions can be represented by an infinite series by Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

I did some thinking with this definition of functions, and realized that the derivative was a linear transformation of functions, and could be represented by a matrix (represented by $D$ above). I also noticed that we the "pseudo-integral" (essentially the integral without the constant), represented by $S$ above, is also a linear transformation.

After playing around, I noticed that $DS=I$ (i.e. taking the pseudo-integral then the derivative of a function results in the function you started out with), while $SD\neq I$ (i.e. taking the derivative then the pseudo-integral of a function does not necessarily give the function you started out with). This seems to contradict the principle that $AB=I\iff BA=I$, so I wanted to inquire about this.

I haven't learnt functional analysis (or any sort of analysis beyond surface level) yet, so I am probably doing something very silly here and I won't understand much of the jargon.

Comment: It's true in finite dimension only.

Comment: OK. Would you mind pointing out the flaw in the proof I was given, and why it only works for finite dimensions?

Comment: How $B = (BA)B$ implies $BA=I$? Also, in your "proof" you uses that $BA=I$ to prove that $BA=I$.

Comment: $B=IB$, so that would mean $IB=(BA)B\Rightarrow IBB^{-1}=I=(BA)BB^{-1}=BA$. Also, I started out with $AB=I$, not $BA=I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found an example of two linear endomorphisms of a vector space such that one of them is a right inverse of the other one, but not a left inverse. It turns out that this is impossible for finite-dimensional vector spaces but, as you have noticed, not for infinite dimensional ones.

Another example is this: consider the space $\Bbb R[x]$ of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients. If $p(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$, let $D(p(x))=p'(x)$ and let $P(p(x))$ be the primitive of $p(x)$ which maps $0$ into $0$. Then $D\circ P=\operatorname{Id}$, but $P\circ D\ne\operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how the proof I provided above breaks down for infinite dimensional vector spaces? Maybe there are some hidden assumptions?

Comment: How do you go from $(BA)B=\operatorname{Id}B$ to $BA=\operatorname{Id}$?

Comment: That assumes that $B$ has an inverse, right?!

Comment: Oh, right. I guess. Thanks for your help, I'm a bit slow.